# Google Speech Recognition Timestamps for Known Transcript

Tags: google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition

I have an audio file and I have an exact transcript of that audio file. I would like to be able to get the timestamps of each word in that specific transcript.

I *don't* want timestamps for for the non-accurate recognized speech. I can already do that, and it is useful, but it's not quite good enough due to the mistakes in the speech recognition.

Does anyone know if this is possible with Google speech recognition?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with Google speech recognition. You have to use other services. Even open source tools exist.